# How to dump struct type data using protocol buffer?

Tags: c++, struct, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c++

I am using `gRPC` where I want to transfer a `struct type object` from `server` to `client` using `protocol buffer`. My desire is to directly dump the struct datatype in a message field.

##### Some of my sample code is given here

`server.cpp` where I am getting a `struct` type object from a function.

```cpp
// sample struct
struct Dummy_Info{
    int age;
    bool presence;
};

// sample function to return struct
Dummy_Info Pass_Dummy_Info()
{
    Dummy_Info obj;
    obj.age = 54;
    obj.presence = 1;
    return obj;
}
```

`sample.proto` file which I desire to make(I am only using here the message which will be used for server purpose)

```
syntax = "proto3";

package abc_xyz;

// Response message from server to client
message Server_Response {
    float val = 1;
   // The following is my desire
    struct variable_for_struct_object = 2;
}

// Request message from client to server
message Client_Request {
    string name = 1;
}

service Service {
    rpc GetAddress(Client_Request) returns (Server_Response) {}
}
```

`server.cpp`

```cpp
// omitted the unnecessary part intentionally. Suppose I have passed the Server_Response as pointer type object and it is `response`
Dummy_Info result;
result = Pass_Dummy_Info();

// The following works flawlessly
response -> set_val(0.5);

// The following I want to prepare
response -> set_variable_for_struct_object(result);
```

`client.cpp`

```
// Here I need to fetch the struct type data
auto data = response_.variable_for_struct_object();
cout << data.presence << endl;
cout << data.age << endl;
```

I don't know this direct dumping is possible or not or maybe I am missing concept.

##### What I am doing right now:

`sample.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";

package abc_xyz;

// The following I have added which mimics my struct type object
message DATA_TYPE{
    int32 age = 1;
    bool presence = 2;
}

// Response message from server to client
message Server_Response {
    float val = 1;
   // The following is my desire
    DATA_TYPE variable_for_struct_object = 2;
}

// Request message from client to server
message Client_Request {
    string name = 1;
}

service Service {
    rpc GetAddress(Client_Request) returns (Server_Response) {}
}
```

After then I have formatted the cpp files as like as follows which is working

`server.cpp`

```cpp
Dummy_Info result;
result = Pass_Dummy_Info();
response->mutable_variable_for_struct_object()->set_age(result.age);
```

`client.cpp` is as like as before.

**Reason** of my desire is to avoid declare the same struct 2 times (one time in `cpp`, later in `proto message format`). If here is any workaround would be grateful to have the direction.

Comment: You have to serialize your struct on the server side and deserialize it on the client side. Since you already are using grpc, then why not turn `obj_data` into another protobuf message and let grpc handle it? Or, if you don't have control over `Create_Dummy_Obj` function: map the result from whatever type it returns to a custom protobuf message, send it over the wire, deserialize it on the client side and map it back to whatever type it was originally.

Comment: @freakish Have you seen the `proto file` I have provided? I guess you mean to use a datatype/message type for my `obj_data`. But I am not getting how to use that. can you please elaborate your suggestion? Moreover, you have mentioned to `serialize` & `deserialize`. Is not it doing here ? Eg: You can reply on behalf of `result` message of Server.

Comment: We don't know what your `obj_data` is. What I'm saying is that create a message, say `message ObjData`, use it inside `message Response` and refactor your code to return `ObjData` from `Create_Dummy_Obj` call. If you can't modify that function (for whatever reason) then add `Convert` function that will convert the original `obj_data` struct to the new `ObjData` protobuf class.

Comment: @freakish I am trying to follow what you have suggested. Also edited the question with the used struct data and function for your convenience.

Comment: @freakish this one is not clear to me as you have mentioned `say message ObjData, use it inside message Response`. Don't I need to declare a `field value` message variable inside this new message `ObjData`, Eg: `message Response{message ObjData{C++_type Field_name = 3;}}`? That one I am not getting how to write/ declare in `.proto` file.

Comment: @freakish Can you kindly take a look again in the question? I have tried to organize the post by added some of my current approach vs desire.

Answer (score 0):

protobuf holds similar data for struct. For more info about pb vs struct can be found at: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

```
syntax = "proto3";

package communication;

message YourData {
  int32 d1 = 1;
  string d2 = 2; 
} 

// Response message from server to client
message Response {
    int32 result = 1;
    // struct obj_data = 2; // I know this will not work and which pushes me to ask the question.
    YourData data = 2;  
}

// Request message from client to server
message Request {
    string name = 1
}

service Dummy_Service {
    rpc GetAddress(Request) returns (Response) {}
}
```

server related code

```
   YourData d; 
   d.set_d1(1);
   d.set_d2("hello");
   response->mutable_data()->CopyFrom(d)
```

client related code

```
 auto data = response_.data();
 cout << data.d1() << ":" << data.d2() << endl;
```

Comment: I was also thinking something like this though I have expected to have something "magical stuff" which can directly parse the `struct type object data's information` into `protobuff message`. I know that for this I have to introduce the struct datatype to the proto file. My struct data has lots of variable and I don't want to again make another message in `proto` file which will lead me to maintain two different file(proto file and cpp header where I have declared that struct).

Comment: you can also see [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/9514) my expectation. I am not sure whether I am thinking in a right way or not.

Comment: You don't have to maintain two types, you can get rid of your cpp struct and use only the one generated from the protobuf. But it would be cleaner to keep two separate types (one for internal processing, one as a dto = data transfer object). Yeah, they have to be kept in sync, but that is not a big cost (typically a struct and its dto don't change often). Also there's no way to generate a (de)serializer out of a cpp struct (or any other language).