# Display runtime error message in gRPC server side and pass it to the client

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using `gRPC` in a project where I have to set and get values from some separate/outside functions. Some functions has case that if they get unwanted value they will `throw runtime error`. By following [this](https://avi.im/grpc-errors/#c) I have got an idea to catch a `error_state` from inside of the gRPC function.

I am giving here some of my approach. A demo source is [this](https://github.com/faaxm/exmpl-cmake-grpc)

`proto file where only including here the client message part`

```
message NameQuery {
    string name = 1;
    int32 cl_value = 2; // This is a user input data which will be passed to the server and then to a outside function
```

[client/src/main.cpp](https://github.com/faaxm/exmpl-cmake-grpc/blob/master/client/src/main.cpp)

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Setup request
    expcmake::NameQuery query;
    expcmake::Address result;
    query.set_name("John");

    int x;
    cout << "give value of x: ";
    cin>> x;
    query.set_cl_value(x);

   // remaining are as like as before
```

[server/src/main.cpp](https://github.com/faaxm/exmpl-cmake-grpc/blob/master/server/src/main.cpp)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Check_Value(const ::expcmake::NameQuery* request)
{
    if (request->cl_value() < 5)
        cout << "request->cl_value(): " << request->cl_value() << endl;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("********** BAD VALUE **********");
}

class AddressBookService final : public expcmake::AddressBook::Service {
    public:
        virtual ::grpc::Status GetAddress(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const ::expcmake::NameQuery* request, ::expcmake::Address* response)
        {
            std::cout << "Server: GetAddress for \"" << request->name() << "\"." << std::endl;
            Check_Value(request);

        // remaining are as like as before
```

After building the project if from client side `5` or greater than `5` is given `server` didn't show any message but running continuously(which is obvious for the `Wait` function of gRPC) where my expectation was it should print in server console

> ********** BAD VALUE **********

Though, in client side I have got all passed value as `BLANK` where I can assume that, `server` didn't perform any process after the `runtime_error`.

So my query is:
1/ How can I see the `runtime_error` message in server side console?
2/ Any `gRPC default system` to pass this incident to the client (Any generic message).

`Note:` In my real example this `runtime_error` message related function is coming from another project where I cannot access to modify.

Comment: You would need to catch the exception from `CheckValue()` and propagate it back via https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_status.html#a5be6d5b99b07855a1458e0167b066038 or https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_status.html#a8f717edd9625cb4886ce6a599e4d47b4. After catching the excepting in a `try-catch` block, you'd be returning something like `gprc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::CANCELLED, e.what());` where `e` is the exception object.

Comment: @Azeem Thanks a lot. It has solved. Also, in the `client` side using `grpc::Status status = stub->GetFWStatus(&context, request_, &response_); if (status.ok() ... else)` the error message has propagated, idea is taken from [here](https://avi.im/grpc-errors/#c).

Comment: Glad to hear that! :) You might want to self-answer this question for posterity. Cheers!

Comment: @Azeem don't know asking about another question is logical here or not, But if you feel it is OK then can you kindly take a look in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127970/how-to-send-struct-type-data-from-server-to-client)?

Comment: TL;DR. You can simply use a nested message in your proto definition for this as any nested type in C++. That should work. You can access it from your response object. Ideally, it should be solved with protobuf instead of creating your own struct in the code. I suggest that you should take a look at the generated pb C++ definitions of your message. You can directly jump to the accessors section and observe the APIs that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

In `server` side I have missed to use the `try ... catch` in a right way.

`server.cpp`

```cpp
try
{
    Check_Value(request);
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; // This will display the error message in server console
    return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::INVALID_ARGUMENT, e.what());
}
```

An awesome resource regarding [error handler in client side is found here](https://avi.im/grpc-errors/#c).

`client.cpp`

```cpp
// Class instance, message instances declaration

grpc::Status status = stub->GetAddress(&context, request_, &response);
if (status.ok())
    // print server response, do the required job
else
    std::cout << status.error_message() << std::endl;
```